# Chrome driver hangs when using user data

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The browser opens but the debugger hangs. If I comment out the `AddArgument` line then it proceeds fine. Any ideas?

```
   var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Ian\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\Ian\\Desktop", chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to want all other Chrome windows closed to work with existing user data.